# .htaccess remove GET completely

Tags: .htaccess

I have dozens of redirects from an old page e.g. index.php?mode=1,2,3,0 and I want to get rid of all GET Params because the new page is anyways just plain html.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mode=17,0,0,0,0$
RewriteRule (.*) /big-mamas-house/ [R=301,L]
```

I thought removing (.*) would already do the trick but then the rule is not applied anymore according to:
http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule can simplified to:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mode=17,0,0,0,0$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /big-mamas-house/? [R=301,L,NC]
```

`?` in the end is needed to strip off any previous query string.